# Linux Vs UNIX - kernel - How to understand the difference?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, bsd, system-v

In 1980's, two most prevalent operating systems came out,

1) *System V* created by AT&T

2) *BSD* created at UOC, Berkeley

Some of the *BSD* variants are *OpenBSD, FreeBSD, MAC OS X*

Some of the *System V* variants are AIX/HP-UX/Solaris

---

*Linux* is created in 1991, which is made of,

*GNU tools(user space) + Linux kernel(kernel space)*

---

Comparing *UNIX kernel vs GNU hurd vs Linux kernel*, **primary**/**relevant** difference to be known to UNIX/Linux kernel user, is in **kernel integration(build) policy** approach,

**In UNIX**, core kernel and service layers(like MemoryMgmt/ProcessMgmt/IPC/..) are statically compiled and linked to create a kernel executable. A single static binary file.

**In GNU Hurd**, core kernel only is built into a static executable and services are built as dynamic modules. At boot up time core kernel gets loaded and stay resident in memory. Core kernel will dynamically load a service layer when it is required. Services will be unloaded when they are not required. Kernel with loadable modules.

Adv/Disadv:

- A single static binary file has less response time.
- Kernel with loadable modules has more response time
- A single static binary file takes more memory since the foot print carries complete static image with all services
- Kernel with loadable modules take less memory

**Linux** kernel integration(build) policy called “Modular kernel”, which is a mixture of above two policies. Hope you got the reason to mention *GNU Hurd*.

---

Mechanics of Linux/UNIX kernel, **1) working of kernel with its services** **2) providing interface to user(shell & system calls)**, were always same, as shown below,

### [image]

---

So, for Linux/UNIX kernel user,

1) **It is more important** to understand the difference in the aspect of **kernel integration(build) policy** approach.

2) If mechanics of UNIX vs Linux kernel, are same, then, one can further think about **less important**  aspect that talks on **different implementation** of service layers(Memory_mgmt_policy/drivers/FileSy stems/.....) using C. why less important? Because, this is an abstraction to Linux/UNIX kernel user and implementation always varies(never same) in each OS and also varies in time.

---

My question:

To understand the difference,Unix vs Linux kernel, Do you agree with the two reasons, mentioned(above)?

If no, please correct me.

Comment: The Gnu project was started in 1983, not 1991. It acquired a kernel in 1991.

Comment: @richard yes you are right!!! GNU project is from 1983. Linux under  *GNU General Public License* came in 1991/92 with GNU utilities added.

Comment: Do you add a cake to a cherry, a cup of tea to a spoon of sugar, a car to some petrol/gas. Do you put a person under a hat.

Comment: @richard Sorry to hide the significance of GNU project. you can edit the query. Am not native speaker to understand your 2nd comment. BTW, do you agree with my understanding, as mentioned in query?

Comment: There is no such thing as “the Unix kernel”. There are many independent implementations of a Unix kernel. Linux is one.

Comment: Linux is a monolithic kernel. Parts of the kernel can be loaded dynamically, but that's not the same thing as a microkernel approach. Linux is not unique in this in the Unix world, many other Unix systems have a monolithic kernel with some dynamically loaded parts.

Comment: @Gilles Linux is monolithic kerenl? What for [kmod](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/kmod.8.html) used? For example, from `Linux/net/socket.c`, how  `sock_register(..)` gets invoked by multiple implementations(say `af_inet.c`) in load phase?

Comment: @overexchange Loading a module adds some parts into the kernel. But the kernel runs as a single memory space. That's the definition of a monolithic kernel.

Comment: @Gilles Looks like monolithic kernel definition given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_kernel) is not the one, I meant in query. You can edit the query. I meant a single static binary file.Query updated